# mysql вопрос по датам

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Добрый! Следующим запросом делаю листинг статистики

```
SELECT SUM(  `bonus` ) , DATE_FORMAT(  `make` ,  '%d %m %Y' ) 
FROM  `trans` 
GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(  `make` ) 
ORDER BY DAYOFYEAR(  `make` ) DESC
```

Проблема в том что если за какой то день в базе не было записей, то этот день в выборке отсутствует, как сделать что бы в выборку попадали все дни по порядку, но в случае отсутствия записей напротив такого дня сумма была 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нам надо создать опорный запрос, который выдаст все даты за требуемый интервал времени к которому потом доклеить наши данные. Для создания такого запроса в MySQL проще всего воспользоваться рабочей табличкой с порядковыми номерами (такая таблица достаточно часто используется в разных ситуациях). Номеров в таблице должно быть достаточно что бы покрыть весь требуемый диапазон времени. Ваш запрос явно рассчитан не более чем на год (из за dayofyear) так что 366 записей было бы достаточно.

```
create table seqnum(X int not null);
-- Первые 8 записей
insert into seqnum values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7);
-- И еще 512
insert into seqnum
select s1.x*64+s2.x*8+s3.x+8
  from seqnum s1, seqnum s2, seqnum s3;
```

Ваш запрос для генерации календаря с количествами за весь 2016 год будет выглядеть так:

```
select DATE_FORMAT('2016.01.01'+interval S.X day,'%d %m %Y'),
       SUM(bonus)
  from seqnum S
  left join `trans` on date(`make`)='2016.01.01'+interval S.X day
  where X<366
 group by S.X
 order by S.X
```

В принципе можно конечно обойтись и без таблицы seqnum, но запрос будет дико громоздким на подобии `select 1 x union select 2 ... union select 7` повторенный три раза и с формулой дня как я использовал при начальной генерации seqnum.

Comment: Сам пользуюсь таким приёмом для получения последовательности дат. В качестве альтернативы таблице можно предложить вьюшку. http://artoodetoo.ru/play-with-ranges/