# postgresql запросы под mysql

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

как мне перевести postgresql запросы на mysql?
Вот собственно запрос

```
with vw as (
      select
        area_id,
        (case when to_char(period, 'yyyy')::INTEGER = %(year)s then to_char(period, 'mm')::INTEGER when to_char(period, 'yyyy')::INTEGER < %(year)s then 0 end) month_num,
        round(sum((case when type=1 then sum else 0 end))/1000000,1) consumption,
        round(sum((case when type=2 then sum else 0 end))/1000000,1) payment
      from clearing_main
        where
        (0 = %(abonent_type)s or abonent_type = %(abonent_type)s) and
        region_id = %(region_id)s and (0 = %(area_id)s or area_id = %(area_id)s)
      group by area_id, month_num
    )
    select
      gs_month_num as id,
      (select sum(consumption)-sum(payment) from vw where vw.month_num < gs_month_num) begin_debt,
      (select sum(consumption) from vw where vw.month_num = gs_month_num) consumption,
      (select sum(payment) from vw where vw.month_num = gs_month_num) payment,
      (select sum(consumption)-sum(payment) from vw where vw.month_num = gs_month_num) debt_plus,
      (select sum(consumption)-sum(payment) from vw where vw.month_num <= gs_month_num) end_debt,
      (select (case when sum(consumption) > 0 then round(sum(payment)*100/sum(consumption), 1) else 0 end) from vw where vw.month_num = gs_month_num) percent
    from generate_series(1, extract('month' from now())::integer) gs_month_num
    order by gs_month_num;
```

тут еще и генерируется месяцы от 1 до нужного месяца.
Я сделал что то похожее, но у меня показывает лишь один месяц.

```
SELECT
    g_month as id,
    (SELECT SUM(consumption)-SUM(payment) FROM y WHERE y.month < g_month) AS begin_debt,
    (SELECT SUM(payment) FROM y WHERE y.month = g_month) AS payment,
    (SELECT SUM(consumption)-SUM(payment) FROM y WHERE y.month <= g_month) AS end_debt,
    (SELECT (CASE WHEN SUM(consumption) > 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(payment)*100/SUM(consumption), 1) ELSE 0 END) FROM y WHERE y.month = g_month) AS percent
FROM (SELECT MONTH(NOW())  AS g_month) g_month, (SELECT area_id,
        (CASE WHEN YEAR(period) = 2016 THEN MONTH(period) WHEN YEAR(period) < 2016 THEN 0 END) AS month,
        ROUND(SUM((CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN sum ELSE 0 END))/1000000, 1) AS consumption,
        ROUND(SUM((CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN sum ELSE 0 END))/1000000, 1) AS payment
    FROM main
        WHERE abonent_type = 1 AND region_id = 79 AND area_id = 7922
    GROUP BY area_id, month) AS y
ORDER BY g_month`
```

Так же в этом `(SELECT SUM(consumption)-SUM(payment) FROM y WHERE y.month < g_month) AS begin_debt` идет обращение к таблице `y` и выдает ошибку что таблица не найдена. Буду благодарен.

Comment: вы generate_series ни как "в лоб" сэмулируете. Можно как тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536013/mysql-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/536109#536109

Comment: И вам запрос надо по хорошему начисто переписать, причем на postgesql, в том виде что сейчас с ним работать невозможно и для БД нагрузка слишком большая с таким кол-вом подзапросов, которые можно было бы свести чуть ли не к одному. А без примера БД с данными в ней помочь вам нереально, запросы вот так просто не пререводятся, проверять и сверять выдачу необходимо

Comment: В том то и дело что запрос нуждается в переработке, но уже в mysql postgresql код не мой, вот и не получается сделать адекватный запрос к таблицам...

Comment: пример таблиц с данными на каком нибудь sqlfiddle бы сделали, тогда было бы о чем говорить. По моему текущему представлению все подзапросы вида `(SELECT SUM(consumption)-SUM(payment) FROM y WHERE y.month < g_month) as begin_debt` раскрываются в что то в виде `SUM(IF(y.month < g_month, consumption-payment,0))`. Т.к. похоже, что это данные из предыдущих строк, возможно их было бы проще получать еще в предыдущих строках в переменные. А подзапрос обращающийся из списка выборки к таблице Y в принципе невозможны

Comment: Согласен с вами при обращение к Y таблице, выводит ошибку что нету такой таблицы, но даже так я не имею представления как обработать запрос, и свести все на минимум, у вас есть варианты? мне очень важно это

Comment: Сделайте create table и несколько insert (что бы даты из разных месяцев были обязательно) и выложите на sqlfiddle.com, надо же на чем то проверять запрос. мне надо почуствовать данные что бы чего нибудь 10 раз не перемножить случайно

Comment: @Mike [ссылка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4254b/1/0)

Comment: @Mike Извиняюсь [ссылка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bdaac) вот

Comment: Ага, так лучше, а то payment 0 везде был

Comment: Интересно, зачем во внутреннем подзапросе в group_by area_id, если во внешнем все тупо собирается до месяца, не взирая на area_id. Хотя учитывая деление на миллион и округление до 1 знака после    запятой мы получаем данные очень далекие от действительности. Так как сейчас, если в каком то area за месяц сумма < 100k, то в отчет она идет как 0. Если мы имеем 10 разных area в каждой из которых почти 100k в месяц, то запрос без group by дал бы в итоге число около миллиона, а так как сейчас он даст 0

Comment: Я не совсем понял вас

Comment: берем сумму меньшую 100к делим на миллион, округляем до 1 знака после запятой, получаем 0. Если сделать такую операцию на каждой строке, то в каждой из них будет 0. Но если мы предварительно просуммируем несколько строк и применим операцию уже к сумме - то результат будет отличатся. (90+90+90+90)/1m=0.4m вот сейчас запрос собирает строки по area_id на каждой из которых делая вычисления, а потом, уже округленные данные с потерянной точностью суммирует

Comment: На тех данных, что вы дали в примере выполните `select round(sum(sum)/10000,1) a,
       sum(round(sum/10000,1)) b
  from main
` и посмотрите как отличаются a и b и это всего 10к, а в вашем запросе там на миллион деление

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы запроса потребуется таблица seqnum, c единственной колонкой `X`, в которой будет 13 строк с порядковыми номерами от 0 до 12 - это замена generate_series.  Дикое количество подзапросов в исходном postgresql запросе вообще было не нужно, все это можно было сделать аналитическими оконными функциями. К сожалению в MySQL таких нет, поэтому я завел переменную (`@ed`) для кумулятивного накопления дебета счета и переноса его в следующую строку как начальное. Итоговый group by и having пришлось применить так как для получения дебита на начало года необходима строка с нулевым месяцем, которая в итоговой выборке postgresql отсутствовала (generate не выдавал строку 0).

```
select month_num,
       round(@ed,1) as begin_debt,
       consumption, payment,
       consumption-payment as debt_plus,
       @ed:=round(@ed+coalesce(consumption,0)-coalesce(payment,0),1) as end_debt,
       (case when consumption>0 then round(payment*100/consumption,1)
             else 0 end) as percent
  from (
    select S.X as month_num, 
           sum(consumption) as consumption,
           sum(payment) as payment
      from seqnum S
      left join (
         select (case when year(period) = 2016 then month(period)
                      when year(period) < 2016 then 0 end) as month_num,
                round(sum((type=1)*sum),1) consumption,
                round(sum((type=2)*sum),1) payment
           from main M
          where region_id = 79 and period<=now()
          group by area_id, month_num
      ) B on S.X=B.month_num
      where S.X<=month(now())
      group by S.X
  ) A, (select @ed:=0) B
 group by month_num
 having month_num>0
 order by month_num
```

Что бы запрос мог выдавать результаты на предоставленном вами образце данных сделал следующие изменения:

1. Убрал проверку abonent_type
2. убрал деление сумм на миллион
3. добавил в предложение where внутреннего запроса `and period<=now()`, потому как ранее записи с годом >2016 выбирались, но относились к месяцу NULL
   что исключало их из итоговой выборки.

Группировку по area_id в внутреннем запросе оставил, что бы она вносила ошибки округления, как делала это в старом запросе из postgresql, возможно такие результаты и ожидались ...

Comment: спасибо большое  вы мне очень помогли) но появился новый нюанс, расчет на 8 месяц не верные получился, на 8 месяц примерно оплачено больше 10 миллионов, но по запросу даже 1 миллион не показывает

Comment: Я сейчас обновлю данные и опять перепроверю, но вам большое спасибо) надеюсь вы поможете еще раз

Comment: @iAxel Результаты внутреннего подзапроса, посмотрите он коротенький, легче разобраться будет. Если дает ошибки, убираете group by смотрите сырые данные которые он отбирает, все ли в них попадает

Comment: ничего не стал убирать) обновил данные в бд и все стало на свои места, спасибо еще раз!

Answer (score 0):

cte есть только в MySQL 8.0 / MariaDB 10.2, но они пока не ga

рекурсивные можно эмулировать с помощью [процедуры](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/22.html)

в вашем случае, можно просто перенести во from-подзапрос

относительно того, что нельзя из подзапроса в части select обратится к подзапросу в части from - продублируйте y (т.е. from-подзапрос) в подзапросах в части select, например:

вместо

select 1, (select 2 from y) x from (select 3) y;

нужно

select 1, (select 2 from (select 3) y) x from (select 3) y;

читабельность будет ужасная, но тут ничего не поделать

для генерации последовательности используйте опорную таблицу или MariaDB емнип 10.1