# Сортировка транзакций по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Приветствую. Столкнулся с проблемой, существует таблица с транзакциями, а в ней столбец с timestump. Необходимо подводить итог остатка на счете в каждый из дней в определенном временном интервале.

Как вариант рассматриваю выполнения запроса для каждого из дней, набирая остаток суммированием всех предыдущих транзакций. Но не считаю, что этот способ корректен. Какое решение можете подсказать?

Демо с данными: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/821821

Comment: Не понятно что Вам нужно. Что за транзакции, какая информация кроме даты по ним храниться. Остаток на счёте считаете или сумму проведённых транзакций? Сумма транзакций элементарно. Для остатков структура базы должна быть несколько сложнее, ближе к бухгалтерским оборотам, где на каждый день/операцию есть начальный и конечный остаток. Тогда и считать ничего не  надо - бери готовое.

Comment: Вот позавчера переводил на MySQL запрос который показывал движение денег и сальдо на начало и конец дня http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582499/  ну он изначально громоздкий, но если присмотритесь там для кумулятивной суммы используется переменная `@ed` ...

Comment: @Sergey http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/821821

Comment: Ну что я могу сказать. Да, с такой структурой у Вас нет другого варианта как каждый раз суммировать все транзакции, начиная с самой первой и до заданной даты. И так для каждого дня периода. Не припомню, чтобы в sql была предусмотрена возможность "итеративного" счёта. Это конечно можно сделать на уровне приложения.

Comment: @Sergey Как считаете, можно ли как-то улучшить структуру?

Comment: В первом комментарии есть наводка