# Не получается составить запрос и сгруппировать по датам

Tags: mysql, запрос, group-by

Здравствуйте. Имеется запрос на выборку данных для статистики по товарам.
Необходимо сгруппировать кол-во заказов, просмотров, сумму заказов и прочие данные. С извлечением вопросов нет.

Главный вопрос состоит в группировке по дням (ещё по неделям и месяцам)

```
SELECT SUM(orders_payed.seller_summ) AS seller_summ,
       SUM(orders_payed.partner_summ) AS partner_summ, 
       SUM(orders_payed.cnt) AS orders_payed_count,
       SUM(visits.cnt) AS count_visits
FROM
  products

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     product_parent_id, 
     SUM(IF(seller_id=2, seller_summ, 0)) AS seller_summ, 
     SUM(IF(partner_id=2, partner_summ, 0)) AS partner_summ, 
     COUNT(1) AS cnt 
   FROM 
     orders
   WHERE 
      status=1 
     AND 
      DATE(payed_at) = "2017-02-16"
   GROUP BY 
     product_parent_id
   ) AS orders_payed
ON orders_payed.product_parent_id = products.id 

LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
     product_parent_id, 
     COUNT(1) AS cnt 
   FROM 
     product_visits 
   WHERE
     DATE(created_at) = "2017-02-16" 
   GROUP BY 
     product_parent_id
   ) AS visits 
ON visits.product_parent_id = products.id

WHERE 
    products.active = 1 
  AND 
    products.active_partners_system = 1 
  AND
    products.parent_id IS NULL 
  AND products.id IN (...)
```

Грубо говоря, сейчас мне приходится делать 7 таких запросов меняя даты, мне нужно делать одним запросом на 7 дней (недель, месяцев).
Т.е. вывести статистику для всех выбранных товаров построчно (по дням).

Понимаю, что сгруппировать нужно в join-ах и как-то все это объединить.

Всем спасибо!

P.S.: Запрос сократил с целью экономии пространства)

**Вопрос был решён созданием дополнительной кеш-таблицы**

> Дополнительная таблица, которая накапливает данные в необходимом разрезе из других таблиц (с использованием триггеров) - лучший вариант для хранения больших объемов информации с целью ускорения работы запросов.

Comment: есть же оператор **BETWEEN**

Comment: Крайне сложно что-то посоветовать, не видя исходных таблиц. Вы бы на sqlфидле каком-нибудь образцы разместили.

Comment: Вы потом замучаетесь статистику за год собирать из нескольких таблиц. таблица лучше одна и возможно партиционирование. https://habrahabr.ru/post/66151/ Остается вопрос а нужна ли столь подробная статистика за такой период. при введении таблицы с суммарными показателями по дням можно совсем старые периоды из visits удалять. надо очень серьезно продумать, а зачем и в каком разрезе может потребоваться информация о посещениях скажем год назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.DT, SUM(count_visits) count_visits,
       SUM(seller_summ) seller_summ, 
       SUM(partner_summ) partner_summ, 
       SUM(orders_payed.cnt) AS orders_payed_count
  FROM (
    SELECT products.id, DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X day as DT,
           COUNT(visits.product_parent_id) AS count_visits
      FROM products
      JOIN seqnum S ON S.X<=7
      LEFT JOIN product_visits visits
        ON visits.product_parent_id=products.id
       and created_at>= DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X day
       and created_at < DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X+1 day
     WHERE products.active = 1 
       AND products.active_partners_system = 1 
       AND products.parent_id IS NULL 
       AND products.id IN (...)
     group by DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X day, products.id
  ) P
 LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT product_parent_id, date(payed_at) DT
         SUM(IF(seller_id=2, seller_summ, 0)) AS seller_summ, 
         SUM(IF(partner_id=2, partner_summ, 0)) AS partner_summ, 
         COUNT(1) AS cnt 
    FROM orders
   WHERE status=1 
     AND payed_at >= "2017-02-16" and payed_at < DATE("2017-02-16")+interval 8 day
   GROUP BY product_parent_id, date(payed_at)
  ) AS orders_payed
    ON orders_payed.DT=P.DT and P.id=orders_payed.product_parent_id
 GROUP BY P.DT
```

Используется генерация дат [как в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536013/mysql-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/536109#536109) таблицу `seqnum` создать как описано там.

Comment: @Solvik на другие периоды две проблемы: 1. интервалы дат, для недели видимо `created_at>= DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X*7 day
       and created_at < DATE("2017-02-16")+interval S.X*7+1 day` для недель или `+interval S.X month AND +interval S.X month+interval 1 day` для месяцев. только стартовую дату лучше на начало недели/месяца делать. И 2. группировка до недели/месяца а не до дня. тут интереснее, думаю использовать  `date_format` http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html с соответствующим форматом что бы включал год и неделю или месяц

Comment: @Solvik Если оставлять группировку до дня то надо тупо расширять интервал выборки но все условия сохранять шириной в один день. т.е. тупо увеличить условие `S.X<=7` до нужного кол-ва дней.

Comment: @Solvik Или я уже мудрить начинаю ... мы же в обоих частях до дня сгруппируем значит ширина периода выборки значения не имеет. так что можно и так и так. пробовать надо :)

Comment: @Solvik думаю надо отдельно решать те 1 и 2 задачи. интервал меняем как нам нравится, в подзапросах P и orders_payed оставляем группировку до 1 дня, что бы данные верно склеились (они же как раз по id и дню клеются. А потом просто меняем последнюю строку GROUP BY что бы собрать до нужного периода, там уже какой нибудь date_format. Ну а количество недель или еще чего нибудь легко регулируется отбираемыми номерами из seqnum

Comment: @Solvik на SO не принята такая развернутая переписка. предлагаю поудалять комментарии. я пока под вопросом свои удалю. потом тут по мере того как не нужны будут

Comment: @Solvik Если там группировку изменить, то оно к датам из первой части (`P`) неправильно приклеится. выполняйте запрос частями. посмотрите что эта вторая часть выдает по дням. потом восстановите группировку до дня всего запроса и сверьте цифры

Comment: @Solvik Я думаю виновата первая часть. там надо подумать что указать в group by по дате и собственно как DT вычисляется. она должна продолжать давать отдельные дни. Так что длину периода надо менять только изменяя максимальный `S.X` и больше ничего там не трогая

Comment: @Solvik Нельзя. Если на 1 запись `P` придется более одной записи `orders` то вверху `SUM(count_visits)` посчитает визиты столько раз сколько записей выйдет

Comment: @Solvik Если итоговая группировка запроса будет не более крупной, чем внутри `P` то можно склеить как вы сказали, только от количества визитов в итоге взять MAX(), а не SUM().

Comment: я все-таки пришел к тому, что проще сделать таблицу, в которую буду суммировать статистику по дням (такую же для месяцев и лет), и все, профит?)

Comment: @Solvik Я бы не днях остановился. Хотя если месяца/годы нужны всегда с 1 числа, почему бы и нет. Правда получаем +3 апдейта (хотя если таблица одна с показателем типа периода можно и за 1) на фиксации каждого посещения. А посещений много ... Но тут конечно надо выбирать где проигрыш в производительности не так критичен на записи посещения или на выборке.

Comment: @Solvik У меня так же работающая табличка есть. в основной трафик пользователей за 5 минут, в кеширующей по дням. правда стандартный запрос на выборку типа дай трафик за период 1.1.2017 16:35 до 1.2.2017 16:34. В итоге кусочки первого и последнего дня собираются по пятиминуткам, а остальные дни по дневной таблице, запросик тот еще, но работает заметно быстрее чем все по 5 минуткам

Comment: спасибо вам огромное, вы мне так помогли) может свяжемся все-таки, хочу вас денежкой отблагодарить, мне как-то неудобно, целый день вас мучил.. кстати теперь из 200к строк получилось в кеш.таблице всего 250 строк)