# Сложные выборки по времени в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Есть таблица в базе, примерно такого вида `id, project_id, value, date_updated`,
то есть таблица хранит значение некоторого параметра для определенного проекта в некоторый момент времени. Обновление таблицы для разных проектов происходит с разными интервалами и может меняться. Появилась задача получения примерного значения параметра для определенного проекта (проектов) на интервале между замерами. Делаю линейную аппроксимацию прямо в запросе, нахожу ближайший замер сверху и ближайший снизу, составляю пропорцию, получаю результат. Примерно так:

```
SELECT SUM(bc1.value+(bc3.value-bc1.value)*TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF($datetime,bc1.date_updated))
        /TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(bc3.date_updated,bc1.date_updated)))) as aproximate
FROM table_name bc1 
LEFT JOIN table_name bc2 ON bc1.project_id=bc2.project_id
                            AND bc1.date_updated<bc2.date_updated
                            AND bc2.date_updated<$datetime  
JOIN table_name bc3 ON bc1.project_id=bc3.project_id
LEFT JOIN table_name bc4 ON bc3.project_id=bc4.project_id
                            AND bc3.date_updated>bc4.date_updated
                            AND bc4.date_updated>$datetime
WHERE bc2.id IS NULL 
      AND bc4.id IS NULL
      AND bc1.date_updated<=$datetime
      AND bc3.date_updated>$datetime;
```

Все работает все прекрасно. А вот теперь вопрос, если я хочу посчитать среднее значение параметра  в определенный час, за последние 30 (90 дней, год...) дней. но с учетом ранее проведенной аппроксимации. то есть хочу получить среднее значение параметра, скажем в 12 часов дня за последние 30 дней. как это лучше сделать?

Comment: $datetime, если не понятно это время для которого производится апроксимация

Comment: Не понимаю, как текущий запрос умудряется брать один ближайший замер сверху и один с низу. Например bc2. он берет все записи в интервале от bc1.date_updated до $datetime, как получается, что там берется именно одна запись ?

Comment: А на вскидку можно взять генератор дат и подклеить ваш запрос к нему, что бы $datetime вычислялось для каждого дня. не знаю на сколько это оптимально и нельзя ли посчитать как то по другому. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536013/mysql-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC/536109#536109

Comment: Запрос работает, потому что в блоке where есть условие что id =null, то есть элемента не существет. То есть таким образом мы выбираем элемент меньший(больший) заданной даты, для которого не существет элемента больше(меньше) его, но так же меньше(больше) заданой даты. Надеюсь понятно написал. На счет генератора дат посмотрю

Comment: столкнулся с проблемой при использовании доп таблицы с числами для генерации дат. при добавлении join на таблицу с числами и везде где используется константная дата, замене ее на что-то типа `date_updated`<('2017-05-15 00:00:00' + INTERVAL `numbers`.`i` DAY), получил что индекс по date_updated не используется! короче запросы при этом начинают дико тормозить, что делать пока не знаю...