# Группировка по временному интервалу в ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Скажем, у меня есть таблица `views` с такими значениями:

```
┌─date───────┬─ip──────────┐
│ 2017-09-10 │ 192.168.1.1 │
│ 2017-09-12 │ 192.168.1.1 │
│ 2017-09-15 │ 192.168.1.1 │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Я хочу получить статистику за 10 дней. Для этого я могу сделать запрос, типа

```
SELECT date, count(ip) as views 
FROM views 
WHERE date > '2017-09-10' AND date < '2017-09-20' 
GROUP BY date
```

И получается вот так:

```
┌─date───────┬─views───────┐
│ 2017-09-10 │ 1           │
│ 2017-09-12 │ 1           │
│ 2017-09-15 │ 1           │
└────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Как сделать так, чтобы отображались даты, когда не было просмотров (т.е. чтобы `views` был = 0), чтобы они красиво отобразилось на клиентской части? Чтобы в выводе присутствовали другие даты, например (2017-09-11 или 2017-09-13).

Использую ClickHouse. Рассматриваю любые варианты решения вопроса.

Comment: не знаю как в clickhouse но стандартное решение - получить опорную таблицу из дат и к ней по left join подклеить таблицу с данными. опорную таблицу из 10 дат можно получить прямо в запросе в виде `select 1 union select 2 ... select 10` и прибавить к числу начальную дату (если у вас в БД есть функции для арифметики с датами)

Comment: примерно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536109/194569 только таблицу создавать ради 10 строк нет смысла, проще union собрать десяток чисел

Comment: @Mike я примерно говорю, там не 10 строк, конечно. щас попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вкратце.

1. Создаете таблицу (назовем ее dates) с полем Date, я выбрал движок [Memory](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/ru/table_engines/memory.html).

   `CREATE TABLE dates
   (
      date Date
   ) ENGINE = Memory`
2. Импортируйте даты, я сгенерировал их так: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Blitss/8f9213428c7075e9a4beb93dc9b11ebd)
3. Используйте эту таблицу, чтобы сделать запрос:

`SELECT 
   date, 
   views
FROM dates 
ANY LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        count(ip) AS views, 
        date
    FROM views 
    GROUP BY date
) USING (date)
WHERE (date > '2017-09-10') AND (date < '2017-09-20')`

Answer (score 0):

Если не хочется создавать таблицу, можно воспользоваться таким запросов для генерации всех дат

```
SELECT
     toDate('2018-01-01') + number AS dates, number
FROM system.numbers
LIMIT :count
```