# Выбрать среднее значение за каждый час и полчаса

Tags: mysqli

Есть таблица, в нее пишет крон каждую минуту онлайн (количество) и время.

```
mysql> SELECT stats_players, stats_timestamp FROM w_1.amx_stats WHERE  `stats_server_id` =19;
+---------------+---------------------+
| stats_players | stats_timestamp     |
+---------------+---------------------+
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:32:02 |
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:33:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:34:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:35:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 20:36:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 20:37:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 20:38:02 |
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:39:02 |
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:40:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 20:41:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:42:02 |
|            31 | 2018-01-30 20:43:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:44:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:45:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:46:02 |
|            31 | 2018-01-30 20:47:02 |
|            31 | 2018-01-30 20:48:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:49:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:50:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 20:51:02 |
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:52:02 |
|            29 | 2018-01-30 20:53:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 20:54:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 20:55:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 20:56:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 20:57:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 20:58:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 20:59:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:00:03 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:01:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:02:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:03:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 21:04:02 |
|            30 | 2018-01-30 21:05:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:06:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:07:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:08:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:09:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:10:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:11:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:12:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:13:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:14:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:15:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 21:16:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:17:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:18:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:19:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:20:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:21:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:22:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 21:23:01 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:24:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 21:25:02 |
|            28 | 2018-01-30 21:26:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 21:27:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 21:28:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:29:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:30:02 |
|            27 | 2018-01-30 21:31:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:32:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:33:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:34:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:35:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:36:02 |
|            20 | 2018-01-30 21:37:02 |
|            20 | 2018-01-30 21:38:02 |
|            21 | 2018-01-30 21:39:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:40:02 |
|            26 | 2018-01-30 21:41:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:42:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:43:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:44:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:45:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:46:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:47:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:48:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:49:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:50:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:51:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:52:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:53:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:54:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:55:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 21:56:02 |
|            25 | 2018-01-30 21:57:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 21:58:02 |
|            24 | 2018-01-30 21:59:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 22:00:02 |
|            22 | 2018-01-30 22:01:02 |
|            20 | 2018-01-30 22:02:02 |
|            23 | 2018-01-30 22:03:02 |
|            16 | 2018-01-30 22:04:02 |
|            16 | 2018-01-30 22:05:02 |
|            14 | 2018-01-30 22:06:02 |
|            13 | 2018-01-30 22:07:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:08:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:09:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:10:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:11:02 |
|            14 | 2018-01-30 22:12:02 |
|            14 | 2018-01-30 22:13:02 |
|            14 | 2018-01-30 22:14:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:15:02 |
|            15 | 2018-01-30 22:16:02 |
--------------------------------------- Вырезал а то в сообщение все не влазит :(
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:44:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:45:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:46:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:47:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:48:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:49:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 10:50:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 10:51:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 10:52:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 10:53:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:54:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:55:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 10:56:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:57:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:58:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 10:59:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:00:03 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:01:03 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 11:02:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:03:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:04:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 11:05:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:06:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:07:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 11:08:02 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:09:02 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:10:02 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:11:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:12:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:13:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:14:02 |
|             4 | 2018-01-31 11:15:03 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 11:16:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:17:02 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:18:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 11:19:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 11:20:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 11:21:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 11:22:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 11:23:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 11:24:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:25:02 |
|             4 | 2018-01-31 11:26:02 |
|             4 | 2018-01-31 11:27:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:28:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:29:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:30:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 11:31:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:32:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:33:02 |
|             5 | 2018-01-31 11:34:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 11:35:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 11:36:02 |
|             9 | 2018-01-31 11:37:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 11:38:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 11:39:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 11:40:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:41:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:42:02 |
|            13 | 2018-01-31 11:43:02 |
|            13 | 2018-01-31 11:44:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:45:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:46:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:47:02 |
|            13 | 2018-01-31 11:48:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:49:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:50:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:51:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:52:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:53:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:54:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:55:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:56:02 |
|            11 | 2018-01-31 11:57:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:58:02 |
|            12 | 2018-01-31 11:59:02 |
|            13 | 2018-01-31 12:00:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 12:01:02 |
|            10 | 2018-01-31 12:02:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 12:03:02 |
|             8 | 2018-01-31 12:04:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 12:05:02 |
|             7 | 2018-01-31 12:06:02 |
|             4 | 2018-01-31 12:07:02 |
|             6 | 2018-01-31 12:08:02 |
|             3 | 2018-01-31 12:09:02 |
|             4 | 2018-01-31 12:10:02 |
|             3 | 2018-01-31 12:11:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:12:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:13:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:14:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:15:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:16:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:17:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:18:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:19:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:20:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:21:02 |
|             1 | 2018-01-31 12:22:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:23:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:24:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:25:02 |
|             2 | 2018-01-31 12:26:02 |
+---------------+---------------------+
955 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Как видим первые записи начались 2018-01-30 20:32:02 (24 часа еще не прошло)
Я пытаюсь вывести среднее значение за каждый час:

```
mysql> SELECT AVG( stats_players ) , HOUR( stats_timestamp )
    -> FROM w_1.amx_stats
    -> WHERE  `stats_server_id` =19
    -> AND stats_timestamp
    -> BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
    -> AND NOW( )
    -> GROUP BY HOUR( stats_timestamp )
    -> ORDER BY  `stats_id` ASC;
+----------------------+-------------------------+
| AVG( stats_players ) | HOUR( stats_timestamp ) |
+----------------------+-------------------------+
|              28.8571 |                      20 |
|              24.2167 |                      21 |
|              18.4167 |                      22 |
|              19.0333 |                      23 |
|              14.6167 |                       0 |
|               7.0000 |                       1 |
|               9.6167 |                       2 |
|               7.6000 |                       3 |
|               4.7333 |                       4 |
|               2.5833 |                       5 |
|               1.7833 |                       6 |
|               1.2167 |                       7 |
|               3.8833 |                       8 |
|               2.5000 |                       9 |
|               5.4333 |                      10 |
|               8.4500 |                      11 |
|               4.7843 |                      12 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+
17 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Отлично, я получил результат за те часы которые есть. Но я просил за 24 часа. Как получить в ответ дополнительно про те часы которых нет. К примеру:

```
+----------------------+-------------------------+
| AVG( stats_players ) | HOUR( stats_timestamp ) |
+----------------------+-------------------------+
|                 NULL |                      13 |
|                 NULL |                      14 |
|                 NULL |                      15 |
|                 NULL |                      16 |
|                 NULL |                      17 |
|                 NULL |                      18 |
|                 NULL |                      19 |
|              28.8571 |                      20 |
|              24.2167 |                      21 |
|              18.4167 |                      22 |
|              19.0333 |                      23 |
|              14.6167 |                       0 |
|               7.0000 |                       1 |
|               9.6167 |                       2 |
|               7.6000 |                       3 |
|               4.7333 |                       4 |
|               2.5833 |                       5 |
|               1.7833 |                       6 |
|               1.2167 |                       7 |
|               3.8833 |                       8 |
|               2.5000 |                       9 |
|               5.4333 |                      10 |
|               8.4500 |                      11 |
|               4.7843 |                      12 |
+----------------------+-------------------------+
```

Так же у меня не получается вывести статистику за сутки по полчаса, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: что касается пропущенных часов, вам нужна либо таблица со всеми часами суток, либо процедура, которая ее буудет делать на лету, чтоб выполнить left join.

Comment: Можно как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536109/194569, только проще, потому что нужно только 24 строки, значит в опорной таблице всего 24 записи делаете. А что бы получить по полчаса добавьте в `group by` скажем `minute(stats_timestamp) / 30`

Comment: @splash58 это что если по пол часа тоже таблицу делать? Так не пойдет, запрос должен быть гибкий.

Comment: Если не нравится временная таблица, делайте массив в языке программирования, заполняйте пустыми значениями, и обновляйте из базы теми, что получили. По другому не получится

Comment: @Mike если добавить то странные результаты, если заменить то тоже. Можно подробнее как изменить запрос что бы получить статистику по 30 минут? Делать таблицу не пойдет, выше ответил.

Comment: GROUP BY (HOUR( stats_timestamp )*60+MINUTE(stats_timestamp))/30

Comment: А чего вы боитесь временных таблиц? вот, например, так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499756/group-time-intervals-by-times-in-which-they-are-occurring/31503456#31503456

Comment: У меня практически во всех БД есть эта таблица, seqnum, ее сложно назвать временной, очень даже постоянная. Я создаю в ней гораздо больше записей, чем надо в разных запросах. А в самих запросах выборку из нее ограничиваю по X<24, например, если нужны часы. Или сделать X<48 для получасовых интервалов и клеить с ней по условию, скажем, `hour(stats_timestamp)+minute(stats_timestamp)/30`. И в итоге она оказывается нужна в десятках запросов в системе. А отдельные таблицы, для каждого случая, конечно делать не надо.

Comment: И главное, при работе в MySQL другого пути просто не существует. Запись не может появится из воздуха, откуда то она должна быть выбрана. Вариантов существует всего три: 1. `select 1 union all select 2 union all ... select 23`, 2. специальная таблица (seqnum), 3. (select @i:=@i+1 from любая-таблица, (select @i:=0) X limit 24`. Второй вариант самый короткий и простой путь. Вот если бы у вас была практически любая другая СУБД, а не MySQL, тогда можно было бы сделать генератор из воздуха.

Comment: А что качается "по полчаса", то конечно надо использовать `floor(MINUTE(stats_timestamp) / 30)` а иначе MySQL еще дробную часть делает и конечно ничего не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения таких задач необходим опорный запрос, который гарантированно вернет нужное нам количество строк. В качестве такого запроса можно использовать специально созданную таблицу с порядковыми номерами (как ее создать описано например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536109/194569)). Дальше нам надо вывести формулу для пересчета номера строки из опорной таблице во время. Для получасовых интервалов можно использовать `часы*2 + floor(минуты/30)` (где floor это целая часть от деления).

Итоговый запрос для получасовых интервалов выглядит так:

```
SELECT AVG( stats_players ),
       concat(floor(S.X/2),':',(X % 2)*30)
  FROM seqnum S
  left join amx_stats A
    on S.X=HOUR( stats_timestamp )*2 + floor(MINUTE(stats_timestamp) / 30)
   and stats_timestamp BETWEEN NOW( ) - INTERVAL 24 HOUR AND NOW( )
 where S.X<48
 GROUP BY X
 ORDER BY X
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c82c64/10)

Comment: Спасибо что стараетесь помочь, но время выполнения этого примера...48 rows in set (17.72 sec)

Comment: я решил с долгим запросом. Просто у меня в одно время пишет не один сервер, и получается что глюк был и за того что одно и то же время повторялось до несколько сот раз :)))) Ну теперь проверим как поведет себя mysql на то что через месяц там будет 15к*60*24*30 записей :)))