# Что и где почитать, чтобы разобраться в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Первый мой вопрос на ресурсе.
Есть задача:
Составить SQL-запрос.

Имеется две таблицы цен на товары:

Таблица `default_price`, содержащая два столбца: идентификатор товара и цена по-умолчанию:

```
id price
10 3000
34 5000
53 5000
```

Таблица `day_price`, содержащая три столбца: идентификатор товара, дата, особая цена на дату:

```
id price date
53 3500 01.10.2017
53 5500 05.10.2017
53 1500 09.10.2017
53 2500 10.10.2017
53 2500 11.10.2017
53 2500 12.10.2017  
10 3500 02.10.2017
```

Необходимо, чтобы SQL-запрос по заданному идентификатору товара (например = 53) и датам начала и конца периода (например с 01 по 10.10.2017), возвращал таблицу следующего вида:

```
   date   price price_type
01.10.2017 3500 особая цена
02.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
03.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
04.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
05.10.2017 5500 особая цена
06.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
07.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
08.10.2017 5000 цена по-умолчанию
09.10.2017 1500 особая цена
10.10.2017 2500 особая цена
```

То есть для каждой даты из периода выбирал либо цену по-умолчанию, если на заданный день нет особой цены, либо особую цену,

если таковая имеется, с указанием соответствующего источника цены для каждого дня.

От готового решения не отказался бы, но больше интереснее самому разобраться, просто подскажите откуда начинать копать?

Comment: Укажите точную версию MySQL. В данном случае это важно.

Comment: Версия не имеет значения.

Comment: Имеет. И очень важное. Жаль, что Вы этого не понимаете...

Comment: От версии зависит какие именно инструменты будут доступны и какой именно синтаксис, у вас слишком специфичная задача чтоб решить ее "общим" способом

Comment: Вот версия на хостинге. Версия клиента базы данных: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

Comment: Для начала посмотрите этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536013/194569 вопрос. Там показан один из стандартных подходов к созданию всех дат из дианазона. На которые во первых надо join подклеить все уникальные id товаров (лучше всего брать из справочника товаров, который у вас не представлен, но он где то должен быть). В итоге получаем выборку где на каждый день диапазона есть строки со всеми возможными товарами. После этого left join подклеиваем к нему ваши две таблицы и с помощью coalesce выбираем ту цену, которая на текущий (в запросе) день есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS temp_calendar;
/* Тут описывается процедура создания временной таблицы и последующим заполением периодом дат */
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp_calendar(dateStart DATE, dateEnd DATE)
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_calendar (
    date DATE not null
        );
        WHILE dateStart <= dateEnd DO
            INSERT INTO temp_calendar VALUES (dateStart);
        SET dateStart = date_add(dateStart, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
/* "Создание таблицы" */
CALL temp_calendar('2017-10-01','2017-10-10');
/* И сам запрос */
SELECT dp.id,
    c.calendar as date,
    ifnull(dap.price, dp.price) as price,
    if(dap.price is not null, 'особая цена', 'цена по-умолчанию') as price_type
from default_price dp
    join (SELECT DISTINCT date as calendar
          from temp_calendar) c on 1=1
    LEFT JOIN day_price dap on dp.id = dap.id and dap.date = c.calendar WHERE dp.id = 53 ORDER BY date;
```

> Спасибо комментаторам!)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь вроде достаточно обойтись стандартным `left join`, если есть таблица, откуда можно взять календарь дат:

```
select dp.id,
    c.calendar as date,
    ifnull(dap.price, dp.price) as price,
    if(dap.price is not null, 'особая цена', 'цена по умолчанию') as price_type
from default_price dp
    /* здесь берете таблицу с датами, чтобы получить календарь, 
       можно его заранее ограничить, если дат много */
    join (select distinct date as calendar
          from calendar_table
          where date between '...' and '...'
         ) c on 1=1
    left join day_price dap on dp.id = dap.id and dap.date = c.calendar
```

Comment: Попробую, но по условию вроде как имеется всего 2 таблицы, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, ваш комментарий мне помог в решении.