# SQL Выборка статистики за промежуток времени

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужен запрос sql, который вернет данные в формате [{дата, общее кол-во заказов, кол-во оплаченных заказов}, {дата следующего дня...}].

Сейчас же если заказов за день не было, то эта запись не возвращается. Как это можно исправить? Нужно вернуть каждые день прошедшей недели с количествами заказов.

```
SELECT
DATE,
COUNT
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS DATE,
        COUNT(id) AS COUNT
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        (
        `created_at` BETWEEN '2018-11-26 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-03 13:10:47'
        )
    GROUP BY
        CAST(created_at AS DATE)
UNION
    SELECT
    CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS DATE,
    COUNT(id) AS COUNT
    FROM 
        orders
    WHERE
    (
        `created_at` BETWEEN '2018-11-26 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-03 13:10:47'
    ) AND `status` = 'paid'
    GROUP BY
        CAST(created_at AS DATE)
    ) AS T
ORDER BY
DATE ASC
```

Comment: Вам нужна опорная "таблица" со всеми датами. Это может быть как обычная таблица, так и выборка вроде `select '2018-11-20' date union all select ....` или выборка из какой нибудь таблицы/запроса производящего последовательные номера которые добавлять к начальной дате. К такой "таблице" по left join подклеиваете свой основной запрос. В 8 версии MySQL можно для создания опорной выборки использовать рекурсивный CTE.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536013/194569