# PHP, МуSql - как объединить несколько запросов в один?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть несколько запросов, к базе данных. Суммарно по времени они выполняются более 10 секунд.

```
"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2015-12-01" AND reviews_data<="2015-12-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.4160809516907

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-01-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-01-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.4150810241699

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-02-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-02-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.2920739650726

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-03-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-03-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.6590950489044

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-04-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-04-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.6340939998627

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-05-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-05-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.5760898590088

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-06-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-06-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.6550948619843

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-07-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-07-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.556088924408

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-08-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-08-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.3690779209137

"SELECT COUNT(reviews_data) as cnt FROM tblkworkreviews WHERE reviews_data>="2016-09-01" AND reviews_data<="2016-09-31" AND reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"", duration=1.4540841579437
```

Подскажите, как их объединить в один?

Comment: `select date_format(reviews_data, '%Y-%m'), count(1) ... group by date_format(reviews_data, '%Y-%m')`

Comment: Работает, но если за некоторые месяцы нет данных, то запрос их пропускает, а нужен 0. Как это можно в Вашем запросе учесть?

Comment: Постройте опорную таблицу месяцев. Или генерируйте её динамически в подзапросе либо, если версия позволяет, в CTE.

Comment: @SmallSani Тогда, как сказал Akina, нужен некий опорный запрос, например как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/536013/194569  (порядковый номер может быть использован для +interval X month, к стартовой дате, что бы генерить месяцы)

Comment: Код, который набивает недостащие элементы в массив - это один простой цикл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Выберите все строки для автора `reviews_author="user" AND login<>"user"` (заменив логины на id'шники и построив индексы, скорее всего сможете ускорить запрос).
2. Используйте вторую часть условия для получения значения `1` или `0` и агрегатную функцию `sum`.

Чтобы решать такие задачки, надо представлять что у вас происходит в базе при запросе и как можно "срезать углы". В общем случае, при запросе база перебирает строки из таблицы и и сравнивает их значения с ограничениями `where`. Если есть подходящие индексы, количество строк, которые надо перебрать, база может сократить.

То есть получается, что каждый запрос у вас это цикл типа:

```
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row == $where) {
        $cnt++;
    }
}
```

Чем больше строк надо перебрать, тем дольше выполняется такой цикл. В вашем случае, с некоторой долей вероятности (чтобы знать наверняка, воспользуйтесь утилитой [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html)), перебираются одни и те же наборы строк.

```
$cnt1 = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row == $where1) {
        $cnt1++;
    }
}

$cnt2 = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row == $where2) {
        $cnt2++;
    }
}

...
```

Если подумать, то это можно оптимизировать, посчитав всё в одном прогоне.

```
$cnt1 = 0;
$cnt2 = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row == $where1) {
        $cnt1++;
    }
    if ($row == $where2) {
        $cnt2++;
    }
}
```

В этом и заключается моё решение. Немного другой способ (но по сути идентичный) вам советуют в комментариях.

UPD для тех, кто в танке :-)

```
select
    sum(`reviews_data` >= "2015-12-01" and `reviews_data` <= "2015-12-31") as `cnt1`
    sum(`reviews_data` >= "2016-01-01" and `reviews_data` <= "2016-01-31") as `cnt2`
from `tblkworkreviews`
where
    `reviews_author` = "user"
    and `login` <> "user";
```

Comment: Цикл на самом деле один. В нем генерируем месяцы и прогоняем их в запросе.

Comment: Если срок большой, то количество запросов вырастает неимоверно.

Comment: Т.е. Ваш метод и так используется, нужно просто уйти от него, сделав не несколько запросов в базу, а всего один.

Comment: Mike в комментарии вопроса уже почти решил проблему, но нужны и пустые записи...

Comment: @SmallSani вас, кажется, смутило что я написал пример на php. Просто я предположил, что вам знаком этот язык. Но я говорю не о коде на php, а о том, то делает база данных, когда вы отправляете ей запрос.

Comment: Не смутил, т.к. одна из меток вопроса и есть php

Comment: Смысл уйти от цикла вообще

Comment: @ЕгорБанин В ваш запрос придется писать эти самые sum() отдельно для каждого месяца. Обычный group by эффективнее и не надо писать sum() для каждого месяца заранее

Comment: @SmallSani кажется вы ничего не поняли. Добавил пример запроса в ответ. Но воздержитесь от копипасты, постарайтесь понять, что происходит в запросе.

Comment: Если запросе у нас будет 40 месяцев то и суммировать будет столько же раз. Сам SUM в запросе - очень тяжелый.

Comment: Минусы не я ставлю, у меня просто кармы не хватает для этого...

Comment: @Mike насчёт не надо писать согласен (хотя, кажется, автору как раз надо). А эффективность обычно лучше измерять. Хотя я думаю, что работать будет одинаково быстро (медленно).

Comment: Егор Банин, благодарю! Вопрос решен и закрыт. Спасибо за тех, кто в танке ) Я только наглядно смог увидеть, что вы имели ввиду в своем ответе.