# INSERT автосгенерированных данных через триггер

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, триггер, insert

Есть таблица `halls`, она имеет поля `max_row_number` и `max_seat_number`.
Есть таблица `seats`, она имеет `row_number`, `seat_number` и `hall_id`.

Необходимо создать триггер:
При добавлении записи в `halls` создавать на каждое место запись в `seats`

Например: при создании зала со значением кол-ва рядов 5 и кол-ва мест в ряду 5, должно создаться 25 записей на каждое место зала:
зал1, ряд1, место1
зал1, ряд1, место2
и т.д

Comment: А с чем именно возникает проблема, с созданием запроса, создающего нужное количество записей или с созданием на основе него триггера ? А то сейчас выходит, что вы задаете сразу 2 вопроса в одном, да еще в виде "выполните за меня работу"

Comment: Собственно генератор делается в виде insert select из таблицы в которой есть записи с порядковыми номерами на максимально встречающееся в жизни кол-во мест/рядов, перемноженной саму на себя (например таблица seqnum из этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/536109/194569 ответа)

Comment: @Mike согласен, не совсем корректно составил вопрос. Проблема с созданием вопроса, впервые столкнулся с таким и инфы особо не смог найти

Answer (score 0):

Основная задача - размножить строки в нужном количестве. Для этого удобно использовать рабочую таблицу с порядковыми номерами (такая таблица достаточно часто используется в разных ситуациях). Номеров в таблице должно быть достаточно на все случаи жизнию

```
create table seqnum(X int not null);
-- Первые 8 записей
insert into seqnum values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8);
-- И еще 512
select (s1.x-1)*64+(s2.x-1)*8+s3.x+8
  from seqnum s1, seqnum s2, seqnum s3;
```

Запрос для генерации рядов и мест в них

```
insert into Таблица(зал, ряд, место)
select id-зала, A.x, B.x
  from seqnum A, seqnum B
 where A.x <= кол-во-рядов AND B.x <= кол-во-мест
```

Остается завренуть это в триггер с подстановкой нужного зала и количеств рядов/мест.